# Designe method inq. - PHP & MySQL

Tags: database

I'm working on a call tracking script for my company and wondering whats the best way to handle the description_field for future updates.

The initial incident would have all the details including the description field filled out. Another use looks at the incident & decides to add more information to the initial description.

As of now I'm updating the records using:

`UPDATE table SET description = CONCAT(description, :dbdescription)`

So,

Is updating the table the way i have above is the best way to update the description field?

Or

Create a new table just for new updates and reference back to the parent record.

Whats the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think to have another historical description table that has a date/time updates is better than updating your original table. i think this is more reliable.

Comment: to add to your suggestion, what if i was append the date and time to to the new comments/description?